# API Token identifier User with Laravel

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm  working in a Hybrid App with Cordova and API REST. For registering users, I'm using the phone number and a SMS for validating the phone (like WhatsApp).

I generate a Token for that User, and this Token is used for consuming the API REST Methods (it's go in the HTTP Header over HTTPs).

I need to create a "Filter" or something similar for my API REST to identifier the user, and not use a query all the times to obtain the user_id, something "automatic" for my controllers but I don't find anything similar...

I could use something like this:

```
Route::filter("auth", function()
    {
        // ...get database user
        if (Input::server("token") !== $user->token)
        {
            App::abort(400, "Invalid token");
        }
    });
```

But how know my controller what user is requesting?

Is this a good solution?

```
Route::filter('auth.api', function()
{

    $token = Request::header('Token');
    $user = User::where('token', '=', $token)->firstOrFail();

    Auth::login($user);

    $result = Auth::onceBasic('username');

    if ($result)
    {
        echo $result;
    }

});
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

What about `Auth::user()`? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users

You can get current authenticated user information.

Comment: Hi! @xjaphx check my possible solution, regards!